# how to use deferred resolve and reject in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I want to use $.Deferred object resolve and reject method. I  referred the following link

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises/

```
function a()
{
var def=$.deferred();
for(i=0; i<object.length;i++)
{
if(i=="some condition") // callback function there so i reject until it completes.
def.reject();
else
def.resolve();
}

}
```

after the function a() completely executed (i.e which contains some callback function) so "a"  function need to wait until the callback complete. so I use def.reject() and other cases I use def.resolve()

but first of all def.resolve() called and then def.reject() called means doesn't matter

function a() need to wait until it contains all callback function completed.

```
$.when(a()).done(function(e)
{
b();
});
```

and then I need to call b() function. so a() function completely executed and then I need to execute b() function.

how can I do this  using deferred object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to *return a Deferred object* from your function.

To use semantics like your example

```
$.when(a()).done(function(e)
{
b();
});
```

You would have to return **a `Deferred` object** from the function `a`, like this

```
function a()
{
    return $.Deferred(function(def)) {

        for(i=0; i<object.length;i++)
        {
                // do whatever
        }

        def.resolve();
    }
}
```

This is similar to what you have.

The differences are that

- you return a new `Deferred` object.  The `a` function as you've written it doesn't return anything, so it gets treated as a synchronous function by jQuery methods that expect a Deferred.
- You don't need to `reject` at any point before the method completes.  You just need to resolve when it does.  The whole point of `Deferred` is that you can execute synchronous code within method that you pass to the `Deferred` constructor.

Comment: i already returned  "defobj.promise()" last in function. but i forget post here. i need only a() function  need to wait until all callback function get completed.

Comment: @SivaRajini, if the objects that you're iterating through themselves use asynchronous callbacks, then you'll need a different method.  It sounds like you might not need an `a` function at all, but something like `$.when.apply`, which can wait for an array of `Deferred` objects to complete.  To be more specific, I'd need to see what the code in the loop looks like.

Comment: i tried your code but it calls b() function automatically before callback function gets completed in a()

Comment: @SivaRajini, this method only works if the code inside `a` is synchronous -- otherwise you're just moving the problem around.  If you have another asynchronous callback that you need `b` to wait for, you have to post the details of that.

Comment: i think u misunderstood my requirement. function a() contains some callback function. i want function a() should wait until the callback function gets completed that's why i use $.when here. because b() function should be called after a() function completely executed (i.e completed callback function).

Comment: @SivaRajini, you need to show a more complete example.  In particular, where does the callback inside of `a` come from?  What is the point of the loop?